# Is it possible to Record audio while playing video without audio simultaneously on same screen on android

Tags: android

I want to develop an app in which i want to perform an activity on same screen showing video only without audio while recording sound
Is it possible to develop on android???

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue?

Comment: I want to develop it by my own...M asking if someone have done it before,is video and voice recorder library can work at same time?